# Symfony2 - Access Denied

Tags: php, symfony, access-denied, user-roles

I am using Symfony2 for my project and I created two pages. One login page and one index page. I have logged in admin account (with `ROLE_ADMIN`) successfully.
However I received 403 Forbidden page with the following error:

> ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException:    "Access Denied" at .\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener.php line 100

And this is my config in `security.yml`:

```
access_control: 
   - { path: ^/vs/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
   - { path: ^/vs/index, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

when I var_dump user. I see that **roles** is empty:

```
private 'roles' => 
    object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[293]
      private 'snapshot' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

And this is the Roles from my `User.php`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
 * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $roles;
```

And this is what I get when using `$user->getRoles()`:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(...\Entity\Role)[397]
      private 'id' => int 1
      private 'name' => string 'admin' (length=5)
      private 'role' => string 'ROLE_ADMIN' (length=10)
      private 'users' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[398]
          private 'snapshot' => 
            array (size=0)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#managing-roles-in-the-database

Comment: Yes, I followed this tutorial.

Comment: Which route is used for the post login redirection ? Is it `/vs/index` ? By the way you should use `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($entity)` instead of `var_dump($entity)` when you deal with Doctrine entities.

Comment: works for me, just tried it. maybe you can post the whole User and Role Entities. Maybe it's something stupid like a typo or something. And make sure to add the role for the user in the db :)

Comment: here are my annotations:    
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
 *
 */
 private $roles;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;

try and change these first

Comment: @LaurentWartel I received an empty roles array when dump($user)
 `public 'roles' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '\TestBundle\Entity\Role' `

Comment: @lackovic10 I used your annotations and then clearn up cache + update DB ... it works now!!!!! thank you very much.

Comment: @lackovic10 could you please phrase the comment as an answer so  rukabillaan can accept it to have the question closed and the right guy get the credit for his effort? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doctrine relation annotations were wrong:

```
/** 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users") 
 */ 
private $roles; 

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles") 
 */ 
private $users;
```